# Meteor email verification

Tags: email, meteor, verification

I am trying to make an email verification in my project using this tutorial:
https://themeteorchef.com/tutorials/sign-up-with-email-verification

I've got method:

```
//server/methods/send-email.js

import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Email } from 'meteor/email';

Meteor.methods({
  sendVerificationLink() {
    let userId = Meteor.userId();
    if ( userId ) {
      console.log("Email has been sent");
      return Accounts.sendVerificationEmail( userId );
    }
  }
});
```

And call this method on client side:

```
//client/form.js

handleSubmit = () => {
    this.validateField('phone', this.state.phone)
    if (this.state.formValid) {
      this.update_User({phone: this.state.phone});
    }
        Meteor.call( 'sendVerificationLink', ( error, response ) => {
          if ( error ) {
                        console.log(error);
          } else {
                        console.log("- There is no errors in Meteor.call -");
          }
        });

  }
```

I am getting an email with link. But when I go this link, nothing happens. 
Meteor.user().emails[ 0 ].verified - doesn't become true.

```
{Meteor.user().emails[ 0 ].verified ? <div>Success</div> : <div>Failed</div>}
```

I don't get the Success text.

I've tried this:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';

Accounts.emailTemplates.siteName = "name";
Accounts.emailTemplates.from     = "name<admin@name.io>";

Accounts.emailTemplates.verifyEmail = {
  subject() {
    return "[name] Verify Your Email Address";
  },
  text( user, url ) {
    let emailAddress   = user.emails[0].address,
        urlWithoutHash = url.replace( '#/', '' ),
        supportEmail   = "support@cryptocean.io",
        emailBody      = `To verify your email address (${emailAddress}) visit the following link:\n\n${urlWithoutHash}\n\n If you did not request this verification, please ignore this email. If you feel something is wrong, please contact our support team: ${supportEmail}.`;

    return emailBody;
  }
};

Accounts.onEmailVerificationLink = function() {
  console.log("Verified");
  user.emails[0].verified = true;
}
```

But it seems I'm doing something wrong.

I am not very experienced in Meteor / backend... So I really hope to find some help here. Imagine cat looking deeply into your soul from "Puss in Boots" movie. That's me right now))

Comment: What router are you using and how are you handling the password reset route which you're altering in your email template?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like Deepak suggested, in react router that would be something like:

```
<Route exact path='/reset-password/:token' component={ResetPasswordPage} />
<Route exact path='/verify-email/:token' component={VerifyEmailPage} />
```

and the VerifyEmailPage could look like:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

import { Accounts } from 'meteor/accounts-base'

export default class VerifyEmailPage extends Component {

  componentDidMount () {

    const token = this.props.match.params.token
    Accounts.verifyEmail(token, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        toastr.error('Could not verify email!', err.reason)
      } else {
        toastr.success('Email confirmed successfully!')
        this.props.history.push('/feeds')
      }
    })
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>{''}</div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about you remove the "return" from

`return Accounts.sendVerificationEmail( userId )`

and try again.

Answer (score 2):

You need to setup a route where you can get and verify the verification token.

Something like what they have done [here](https://themeteorchef.com/tutorials/sign-up-with-email-verification#tmc-confirming-the-users-email-and-logging-in), in the tutorial that you are following.

Basically, get the verification token on the frontend, call the Account method `Accounts.verifyEmail` with verification token as parameter.